# How do I disable zoom in InAppWebView in Flutter?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart

I am using the [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview#-readme-tab-) dependency for my Flutter App.

I want to disable the zoom-in aspect for `iOS` but I couldn't understand how to do it while reading the [docs](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview). 
I saw they had a property for Android called `supportZoom` that can be set to `true` or `false` to enable and disable zooming.

The only zooming related property I found in the In-appWebView iOS specifications was 
`maximumZoomScale` and `minimumZoomScale` but I can't understand how to implement this to disable zooming.

Is there a way to achieve this for iOS?

Answer (score 8):

```
initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
  crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
  supportZoom: false,
),
```

put it in crossPlatform:InAppWebViewOptions, according to the doc `supportZoom` is crossplatform Option

Answer (score 2):

please find:

```
crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
    supportZoom:false, // adding this will disable the zoom
    //....
)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation why this answer is a solution to the question.

Answer (score 0):

On version 6 `InAppWebView` past answers can do anymore, you can set from `onWebViewCreated` like this:

```
onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
  webViewController = controller;
  webViewController?.setSettings(
    settings:InAppWebViewSettings(builtInZoomControls:false)
  );
},
```